# how to solve problem with vuejs not detected

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

quand j'execute index.html j obtient {{name}} toujours vuejs est non detecté

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
    <title>learn vuejs</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="j">{{ name }}</div>
    <script src="js/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script >
new Vue({
  ele: "#j",
  data: {
    name: "welcome to vue",
  },
});</script>
  </body>
```

Comment: I would recommend that you [go through their documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) first.

Comment: Also please stick to English on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Just used this code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#j",
  data: {
    name: "welcome to vue",
  },
})
```

Don't use `ele` , just use `el`

Comment: I'm glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

you can set an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  new Vue({
    el: '#j',
    // define data - initial display text
    data: {
      name: "welcome to vue",
    }
  })
})
```